# Mass SQL Wordpress Meta Key deletion

Tags: plugins, post-meta, mysql

hi i am newbie with SQL data base so forgive my dumbness i have installed KK Star rating plugin on my wp site which noticed its recording lot of entries and my db size is over 280 MB and 188MB is wp_postmeta table. uninstalled the plugin and i want to run sql query to delete all postmeta with kkstar recorcs. the meta key record is: kksr_fingerprint_default so please give me correct command line to run thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `{PREFIX}post_meta` WHERE meta_key = 'kksr_fingerprint_default'
```

{PREFIX} is the string `$table_prefix` defined in wp-config.php; of course be careful in run SQL DELETE, create a table backup and (maybe) execute first a single line deletion to check the result

```
DELETE FROM `{PREFIX}post_meta` WHERE meta_key = 'kksr_fingerprint_default' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you back up your database. :)

If you're wanting to run a SQL command directly - perhaps using phpMyAdmin - the query would be

`DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'kksr_fingerprint_default'`